# MAX function in Excel: is it possible to provide the range by means of variables?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write an excel formula to perform the MAX of a range.
The default formula accepts references as the boundaries of the range of arguments:

`=MAX(A1:A10)`

I want to provide the boundaries of the range as variables, by inputting them in dedicated cells, something like:

`=MAX(A"number of row taken from the content of cell B2":B"number of row taken from the content of cell B3)`

See the attached screenshot.

Is this format supported by Excel? If yes, what's the correct syntax? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Look into the function `OFFSET()`, it has number of rows, number of columns that you can use for your `MAX()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
=MAX(INDEX(A:A,B2):INDEX(A:A,B3))
```

---

Cool to know, it doesn't matter if you reference `B3` or `B2` first. The formula will re-arange the referencing to a valid range.

Answer (score 0):

Or, this one :

```
=MAX(INDIRECT(("A"&B2&":A"&B3)))
```

[image]

Comment: Found it!

`=MAX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(B2;1)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(B3;1)))`

This also worked, as suggested by @JvdV, and it's much slimmer:

`=MAX(INDEX(A:A;B2):INDEX(A:A;C2))`

While this provides a #REF! error:

`=MAX(INDIRECT(("A"&B2&":A"&B3)))`

Thanks everybody!

Comment: The formula is worked for me, please see my edited post sceenshot.